# 多次元配列の複数条件による検索

Tags: php, array

皆様

お世話になります。
検索数が多くないこともあり、CSVで検索システムを作成しようとしております。

formからデータを取得し、$value_1で都道府県をチェックボックスで選択、$value_2で果物か野菜をラジオボタンで選択し、多次元配列をforeachで検索し、条件に合った配列を吐き出してテーブルを作成しようとしています。

しかしながら、以下の現象がおきています。
Case 1 :青森県・果物・・で検索⇒２番は出てきても、６番が検索でヒットしない
Case 2 :埼玉・野菜・・で検索　⇒検索結果がヒットしない

検索のロジックが誤っているのでしょうか？ご指導をお願いします。

```
[CSVデータ]
1,千葉県,果物,みかん
2,青森県,果物,りんご
3,埼玉県,野菜,トマト
4,千葉県,野菜,ブロッコリー
5,埼玉県,野菜,ほうれんそう
6,青森県,果物,パイナップル
7,埼玉県,果物,桃
```

【PHPコード】

```
echo '<table border="1"><tr><th>#2</th><th>都道府県</th><th>種別</th><th>名前</th></tr>';

$value_1[0] = "青森県";
$value_1[1] = "埼玉県";
$value_2 =  "果物";

echo $value_1[0];

foreach($newarray as $v){ 
    if($v[2]== $value_2){
                if(preg_grep("/".$v[1]."/",$value_1)){ 
                echo "<tr>\n";
                echo "<td align='center'>".$v[0]."</td>\n";
                echo "<td>".$v[1]."</td>\n"; 
                echo "<td>".$v[2]."</td>\n"; 
                echo "<td>".$v[3]."</td>\n"; 
                echo "</tr>\n";
                $n = $n+1;
                }
          }else{        
        echo '<br>　条件を入力して検索を押してください。';
        break;
    }

}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: `if($v[2]== $value_2){ ... } else { ...; break; }` となっていますので、`果物` 以外の行で for loop が終了してしまいます。つまり、CSV データの `3,埼玉県,野菜,トマト` の行で検索が終了することになります。

Comment: ボンミスでした。ご指導ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/62457/%e5%a4%9a%e6%ac%a1%e5%85%83%e9%85%8d%e5%88%97%e3%81%ae%e8%a4%87%e6%95%b0%e6%9d%a1%e4%bb%b6%e3%81%ab%e3%82%88%e3%82%8b%e6%a4%9c%e7%b4%a2#comment68325_62457)を[回答として転記](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2645/9820)いたします。

> `if($v[2]== $value_2){ ... } else { ...; break; }`となっていますので、`果物`以外の行で for loop が終了してしまいます。つまり、CSV データの`3,埼玉県,野菜,トマト`の行で検索が終了することになります。

下記のように`else`以下のコードを`break`以外に書き換えてみてください。

```
<?php
echo '<table border="1"><tr><th>#2</th><th>都道府県</th><th>種別</th><th>名前</th></tr>';
$value_1[0] = "青森県";
$value_1[1] = "埼玉県";
$value_2 =  "果物";
$newarray = array(
  array(1, "千葉県", "果物", "みかん"),
  array(2, "青森県", "果物", "りんご"),
  array(3, "埼玉県", "野菜", "りんご"),
  array(4, "千葉県", "野菜", "ブロッコリー"),
  array(5, "埼玉県", "野菜", "ほうれんそう"),
  array(6, "青森県", "果物", "パイナップル"),
  array(7, "埼玉県", "果物", "桃")
);
echo $value_1[0];
$n = 0;
foreach($newarray as $v){ 
    if($v[2]== $value_2){
        if(preg_grep("/".$v[1]."/",$value_1)){ 
            echo "<tr>\n";
            echo "<td align='center'>".$v[0]."</td>\n";
            echo "<td>".$v[1]."</td>\n"; 
            echo "<td>".$v[2]."</td>\n"; 
            echo "<td>".$v[3]."</td>\n"; 
            echo "</tr>\n";
            $n = $n+1;
        }
    }else{        
        echo '<br>　条件を入力して検索を押してください。';
        //何らかの処理
        continue;
    }
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```